# ROS Indigo OpenCV3: undefined reference

Tags: ros, libopencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! When I try compilling project [rpg_monocular_pose_estimator](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_monocular_pose_estimator) and I get:

```
Building CXX object rpg_monocular_pose_estimator/monocular_pose_estimator/CMakeFiles/monocular_pose_estimator.dir/src/monocular_pose_estimator.o
Linking CXX executable /home/tuuzdu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/monocular_pose_estimator/monocular_pose_estimator
/home/tuuzdu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmonocular_pose_estimator_lib.so: undefined reference to `cv::line(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
/home/tuuzdu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmonocular_pose_estimator_lib.so: undefined reference to `cv::findContours(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int, cv::Point_<int>)'
/home/tuuzdu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmonocular_pose_estimator_lib.so: undefined reference to `cv::circle(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

libmonocular_pose_estimator_lib.so compillig normal.
I have ROS Indigo and ros-indigo-opencv3.nd ros-indigo-opencv3.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214843/ros-indigo-opencv3:-undefined-reference/) by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2015-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-07-30**:
Do a catkin_make VERBOSE=1 and paste in the linker line.  Also get output that shows what header file directories were used (delete monocular_pose_estimator.o, or rebuild from scratch).  Also see http://answers.ros.org/question/214043/use-ros-indigo-opencv3-alongside-248/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for advise. I solved problem with different versions of `opencv`. Because prebuild `cv_bridge` use `opencv 2.4.8`, I rebuilt it from source with `opencv 3.0`.

---

Originally posted by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) with karma: 85 on 2015-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0